# Object Reference not set to an instance or Index out of range error while adding values to lists

Tags: asp.net

Below is my class file which have different names than the one that is used in the project.

```
public partial class College
{
public List<Students> Students;
}
public partial class Students
{
public List<Activity> Activity;
}
public partial class Activity{
public List<string> Name;
}
```

Below is my aspx.cs code

```
            College.Students.Add(new Students{ studentno= studentnumber.text});
            int index2 = College.Students.FindIndex(c => c.studentno== lineno);
            College.Students[index2].Activity= new List<Activity>();
            College.Students[index2].Activity.Add(new Activity{ });
            int k = (College.Students[index2].Activity.Count) - 1;

            College.Students[index2].Activity[k].Name = new List<string>();

            string ctrlStr = String.Empty;

            foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form)
            {
                if (ctl.Contains("Name"))
                {
                    ctrlStr = ctl.ToString();
                    College.Students[index2].Activity[k].Name[0] = (Request.Form[ctrlStr]);--- It errors out here...not understanding the reason...Am i missing any line of code

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Change the declaration of the lists in your classes to:

```
public List<Students> Students = new List<Students>();
```

By doing simply `public List<Students> Students;` you're saying that `Students` exists but not actually setting it up (you're setting it to `null`) so you can't use any of the methods or properties that come with a `List<T>` until you initialise it.

**Index out of range**

This line throws an Index out of range

```
College.Students[index2].Activity[k].Name[0]
```

because even though you've newed up `Name` to a `List<string>` you haven't added anything to it yet so you're trying to reference a non-existent index.  Insetad of that, use:

```
College.Students[index2].Activity[k].Name.Add((Request.Form[ctrlStr]);
```

Comment: This is just the first problem, though.  He also needs to learn that he's working with a different instance of his class on every request - every postback or event will recreate those lists.

Comment: Also, do the same for Activity and Name.

Comment: @Richard Schneider: Activity and Name both get newed up in the code sample, but I'd used the plural of _lists_ and _classes_ to suggest this was just an example.  Obviously it's good practice not to leave your objects in an unusable state from the start :)

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: That's true, but I don't know if that's really within the scope of the question which was specifically about the two exceptions... Also, I'm going to stick my neck out and say that 'Janet' is a 'she' rather than a 'he' ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize Lists

```
public partial class College
{
    public List<Students> Students = new List<Students>();
}
public partial class Students
{
    public List<Activity> Activity = new List<Activity>();
}
public partial class Activity{
    public List<string> Name = new List<string>();
}
```